# Backstack - pop if activity is type of something

Tags: android, android-activity

I have situation, where I always need to recreate activity when starting one so I can't use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

Is there a way to look onto backstack and pop out last if it's the same activity?

I found a way by using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and overriding `onNewIntent` method.

```
@Override
  protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
      finish();
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
```

This works, but i wonder if there is some better way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you considered using Fragments? You can put them on backstack and retrieve as you wish.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: @SaranSankaran Oh, I thought it has same behavior as SINGLE_TOP in my case, but now I've read documentation more carefuly, and it looks that it solves my problem, thanks.

Comment: I have posted a answer. Please mark it as correct answer

Comment: You can achieve this by setting the android:noHistory attribute to "true" in the relevant <activity> entries in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` for your purpose. Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)